# How to add a button on outlook toolbar to a custom form?

Tags: outlook, configure

Hi I have an Outlook form that I'd like to provide ready access to by adding a button or link to it on the outlook toolbar.  How can I customize the toolbar to do this?

Essentially, a single click of the button on the toolbar should bring up the custom form.

This should work in Outlook 2003 and 2007 (preferably).  If it only works in 2007 that would be acceptable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, I guess the correct way would be to create and deploy an add-in.

Take a look at this example in the toolbar section on how to create a button in your addin.

http://www.packtpub.com/article/microsoft-office-outlook-programming-vsto-c-sharp-part1

You then will need the click handler to open you custom form.

Take a look a the code here for that on SO [How do I create a custom Outlook Item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842285/how-do-i-create-a-custom-outlook-item)